# linear-gradient affecting background-size:cover

Tags: css

The code I've posted is doing what I want, but I'm wanting to remove the `linear-gradient` from the CSS. The problem is that when I take it out it's affecting how the background image displays.

```css
.hero-cover {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,.55),rgba(0,0,0,.55)),url(http://monstacdn.com/dd/images/assets/cover.jpg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,.55),rgba(0,0,0,.55)),url(http://monstacdn.com/dd/images/assets/cover.jpg);
  background-position: 0 0,50% 100%;
  background-size: auto,cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="section hero-cover">
  <div style="padding:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just removing the gradients from the `background-image` declarations without also modifying the `background-position` and `background-size` declarations, that's where the problem lies. When you do that, the first value in each of those declarations then applies to the image, and the second value becomes unused. This is what causes the image to display differently. (Note that gradients are also considered images in CSS.)

The takeaway here is to be very careful when modifying, or adding or removing, layered backgrounds. If your background styles are spread across multiple longhand declarations, make sure you edit all of them. In this case, you need to also remove the `0 0` from `background-position` and `auto` from `background-size`:

```css
.hero-cover {
  background-image: url(http://monstacdn.com/dd/images/assets/cover.jpg);
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="section hero-cover">
  <div style="padding:100px;"></div>
</div>
```